# alpha calculation in complementary filter

Tags: android, filter, sensor-fusion

I am using complementary filter for sensor fusion. The equation for complementary filter I am using is

> angle=(1-alpha)*(angle+gyro*dT)+(alpha)*(accel_mag_angle)

I have some confusion about the calculation of alpha. I read somewhere that alpha is calculated using the formula

```
alpha= dA/(dA+dT)
```

where dA is the rate at which you want the values to change (which refers to the cutoff frequency of the filter) and dT is the sampling time. I am using SENSOR_DELAY_UI. The sampling rate of UI is around 15Hz. I used alpha=0.2(by trial and error method) and the app worked fine. But later I realised according to the equation I cannot use alpha=0.2(theoretically) since it will give me a cut off frequency of 60Hz and my sampling frequency is only 15Hz. Is my cut off frequency calculation wrong ? or is my understanding of the equation is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't sweat it. If you find `alpha=0.2` satisfactory by trial and error, just use it. Filters have to be tuned in practice anyway. The theory helps as where to start but you (usually) cannot avoid tuning.

I don't see anything wrong with a 60 Hz cut off frequency. It means that motions above this frequency are cut off. And it is a good thing, since they are most likely noise anyway.

Comment: similar question please help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095785/how-to-determine-the-parameter-alpha-of-a-complementary-filter