# How to determine the parameter alpha of a Complementary Filter?

Tags: filter, signal-processing, robotics

I know that the Complementary Filter has the functions of both LPF and HPF. But I think my understanding on the principal behind it is still unclear.

I am quite new on digital signal processing, and maybe some very fundamental explanations will help a lot.

Say I have a Complementary Filter as follows:

```
y = a * y + (1 - a) * x
```

Then my parameter `a` may be calculated by

`a = time_constant / (time_constant + sample_period)`,

where the `sample_period` is simply the reciprocal of the `sampling_frequency`.

The `time_constant` seems to be at my own choice.

**My Questions:**

1. What is the theory behind this calculation?
2. How do we choose the `time_constant` properly?

<sub>**Note:** I also [posted this question on *robotics*](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1717), as the answers there are likely to be slightly different in emphasis.</sub>

Comment: Multi-posted to [Robotics](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1717/37).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the theory behind this calculation?

For a human readable introduction I would recommend:
[The Balance Filter: A Simple Solution for Integrating Accelerometer and Gyroscope Measurements for a Balancing Platform](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9rLLz1XQKmaLVJLSkRwMTU0b0E/view?usp=sharing).

> How do we choose the time_constant properly?

Intuitively, the `time_constant` is the boundary between trusting the high-pass and the low-pass filter part. For shorter times than the `time_constant` you trust the high-pass filter part more, and for longer times you trust the low-pass part more.

Usually, you have some experience with the physical process you are dealing with and you can *guess* at least the order of magnitude of the `time_constant`. For example, if you are fusing accelerometer and gyro data (which I assume you do based on your other question), something between 0.5-1 second is a reasonable first guess. Then, you start tuning your filter by analyzing its performance on actual data and adjusting `a` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! But I am actually fusing gyroscope and the magnetometer. I still don't get it. Cutoff frequency makes sense to me, whereas the so called time_constant doesn't. I read somewhere that time_constant is "how long the signal acts on" What does that mean? I mean the signal is always there and "acts on", right? How do you know 0.5-1 sec is a good guess please?

Comment: I know it from practice: I used the gyros exclusively to get the orientation and found that they work well for 0.5-1 seconds but after that they start to drift considerably. I wouldn't make a big fuss over getting an accurate `time_constant` because it is just an *estimate*. You need to tune your filter anyway after setting the `time_constant`: you analyze the performance of the filter on actual data and adjust `a` (or the `time_constant`, which is equivalent) accordingly.

Comment: You will find that a fairly wide range of the `time_constant` gives almost equally good performance (yet another reason why I wouldn't make a big fuss over the accuracy of the `time_constant`).

Comment: my problem is that my tuning of the filter seems to be data-specific. i.e, e.g. 0.98 works best on dataset1. But 0.98 gives a rather bad result on dataset2. 0.996 works good for dataset2. So i have no idea how to tune it

Comment: So I am trying to grasp the theory behind it and actually really CALCULATE the value out.

Comment: @perfectionm1ng I don't think there is a more reliable way than tuning on actual real dataset. If you relax your requirements a bit, how does 0.996 perform on dataset1? There is one more thing, I will update the answer.

Comment: OK, I won't update this answer, I answered your other question instead.